# Sum of squares regression proof

Tags: proof-explanation, regression

Could anyone show me how to prove the following:

$$SS_{reg} = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}(\hat{y}_{i} - \bar{y})^{2} = \dfrac{\sum_{i = 1}^{n}[(x_{i} - \bar{x}) (y_{i} - \bar{y})]^{2}}{\sum_{i = 1}^{n}(x_{i} - \bar{x})^{2}}$$

I am unsure about what context to provide but the proof my textbook has is a little confusing, so I was hoping someone else had a better way of doing this.

To provide a little more context, the question is about simple linear regression model with OLS estimators

Comment: Links to questions or equations are frowned upon. See Nash J's edit for how to typeset equations using mathjax. Also your question may soon be closed for lack of context because it doesn't give any indication of where you're stuck.

Comment: Hey thank you for the clarification, I will update the question with Nash's edit and add some context!

Comment: A good question then would be to reproduce the calculation in the textbook (or part of it) along with a description of which pieces you don't understand. Otherwise we don't know what we're trying to be less confusing than.

Comment: Yeah I apologize for that, I wanted to try and paste a picture of the entire thing but I can only have a link to it and I am fairly unfamiliar with the latex like language mse supports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment:

In MSE the context, unlike in Cross Validated, is not trivial, so it is worth to mention that you are talking about the simple linear regression model with OLS estimators.

Answer:

Assuming $y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i + \epsilon_i$, $i = 1,...,n$. The OLS estimator of $\beta_1$ and $\beta_0$ are
$$
\hat{\beta}_1 = \frac{\sum (x_i - \bar{x}_n)(y_i - \bar{y}_n)}{\sum (x_i - \bar{x}_n)^2},  \quad \hat{\beta}_0 = \bar{y}_n - \hat{\beta}_1 \bar{x}_n,
$$ 
thus replace in $SSreg$ the $\hat{y}_i$ with $\bar{y}_n - \hat{\beta}_1 \bar{x}_n + \hat{\beta}_1x_i$ and show that 
$$
SSreg = \hat{\beta}_1^2\sum(x_i - \bar{x}_n)^2, 
$$
now replace $\hat{\beta}_1$ with its explicit form and cancel out the $\sum(x_i - \bar{x}_n)^2$ to get the answer.

Comment: Thank you! This makes it a little more clear